# Problems Using RegisterClassEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

In my Win32 C++ DLL I find that if I try to use `RegisterClassEx` this way it works just fine:

```
WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wx.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;        // function which will handle messages
wx.hInstance = GetCurrentModule();
wx.lpszClassName = pClassName;
atomRet = RegisterClassEx( &wx );
```

However, when I try to use `RegisterClassEx` this way, it fails, `atomRet` is set to zero, and the exception text simply states, "The parameter is incorrect."

```
WNDCLASSEX * _pWndClassEx;
_pWndClassEx = (WNDCLASSEX *)malloc( sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) );
_pWndClassEx->cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
_pWndClassEx->lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;        // function which will handle messages
_pWndClassEx->hInstance = GetCurrentModule();
_pWndClassEx->lpszClassName = pClassName;
atomRet = RegisterClassEx( _pWndClassEx );
```

I noticed in the MSDN documentation for `RegisterClassEx` that it is defined as follows:

```
ATOM WINAPI RegisterClassEx(
  __in  const WNDCLASSEX *lpwcx
);
```

Does this mean that `lpwcx` must be pointing to statically allocated memory?  That is, it cannot be pointing to dynamically-allocated memory (allocated using `malloc`)?  Thank you.

Comment: In your second example, `_pWndClassEx` is not initialized and thus is not properly pointing at any valid memory location, dynamic or otherwise. If that wasn't a mistake while posting the code here, then it might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: Ugh, learn how to use a project template in Visual Studio so that this code crashes immediately in the Debug build.  You need all the help you can get as long as you don't understand pointers.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I understand pointers just fine.  My expertise is in working with embedded firmware and low-level hardware drivers.  I've found myself thrown into a project where I have to get some higher level code working using the Win32 API.  I'm not nuts about it either, but sometimes we have to grow a bit.  Take a look at the accepted answer.  A big part of my problems (at least in this case) is just not understanding how the VS compiler works.

Comment: I'm debating whether to roll back your edit to make my comment relevant again.  Surely you understand pointers well enough to see why anybody would contemplate making such a comment from the original version of it?

Comment: @Hans Passant: I saw and responded to your comment, *after* fixing my example.  I apologize for the confusion, but I did state that the memory was allocated using `malloc` in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example,

```
WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
```

the declaration of `wx` is also zero-initializing all the fields.

In your second example, you don't show how `_pWndClassEx` is being initialized, but you mention getting memory for the structure using `malloc()`.  To be equivalent to the first example, you'll need to clear out the memory returned from `malloc()`:

```
memset( _pWndClassEx, 0, sizeof(*_pWndClassEx));
```

Otherwise the fields that you don't explicitly assigned values to will have indeterminate values (and in particular in a debug build, the memory returned from `malloc()` will be set to `0xcd` if I remember right, so any pointers and handles in the `WNDCLASSEX` struct will have invalid values).

Comment: I forgot to put the `malloc` statement in my example, but it was there in my working code.  You get the Eagle Eye award for noticing the statement about it at the bottom, though.  Good catch!  I did the `memset`, as you suggested, and it works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you do:

```
WNDCLASSEX * _pWndClassEx;
```

you aren't allocating any memory for the structure. You need to do something like:

```
WNDCLASSEX * _pWndClassEx = new WNDCLASSEX;
```

before you can assign to the members in the structure.

However, I don't see any reason for dynamically allocating a `WNDCLASSEX` structure, because you really don't need it once you call `RegisterClassEx`.

Comment: My apologies, I put this post together late yesterday, I was quite fatigued, and I forgot to include my `malloc` statement.  It is there now.